# YAML config file in Silex Framework with dynamic replacement

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, yaml, silex

I created a configuration provider that process configuration in yaml file for silex.
Everything is ok ! even `import` feature work great. 
the only problem that I have is with dynamic replacement for parameters surrounded with `%%` parameters.

```
base_path: /my/path/to/base
paths:
    web_path: %base_path%/web
    upload_path: %web_path%/uploads
```

I don't really know if the Symfony Configuration component can process the data this way.

Comment: As I know Symfony Configuration component can't process data this way. Try to make postprocessing after load.

Comment: I already made a post processing for `import` and merge ! but I'm really stuck with **dynamic replacement** !!
I have many ideas about to process the data :
- copy configuration array to simple one level array, and use it when looping through the original array
- looping and recursively replace
- lopping and extract `%%` parameters and its position and made a replace

I don't really how to deal with that !!

Comment: I think that it is good idea about 2-nd plain config. Try also to look how DI component `DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag` resolves parameters. Or find ready decision. I can't give exact advice.

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will help you

```
function _flattenArray($array, &$flatten, $index = null, $path = null)
{
    if (\is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            _flattenArray(
                $v,
                $flatten,
                (isset($index) ? $index . '.' : '') . $k,
                (isset($path) ? $path : '') . '[' . $k . ']'
            );
        }
    } else {
        $flatten[$index] = [
            'path' => $path,
            'value' => $array,
        ];
    }
}

$config = ...; // load config

$flatten = [];
_flattenArray($config, $flatten);

$parameterBag = [];
foreach ($flatten as $k => $v) {
    $parameterBag[$k] = $v['value'];
}

$parameterBag = new \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag($parameterBag);
$parameterBag->resolve();
$parameterBag = $parameterBag->all();

$propertyAccessor = \Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
foreach ($parameterBag as $k => $v) {
    if ($v === $flatten[$k]['value']) continue;
    $propertyAccessor->setValue($config, $flatten[$k]['path'], $v);
}

dump($config);
```